# Highlighting a portion of a 3D model in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, react-three-fiber

hi im currently trying to make a highlighter tool that’ll highlight wherever the user draws on over the 3D object. right now, i’m creating a MeshLine using the points where the mouse hovers over. the problem with this is that the “highlight” looks like it sticks out of the object.

Example 1(https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1Coi.png)
Example 2(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hI6C.png)

is there a way to make the MeshLine look like it’s a flat object rather than just have it extruding out?